# Passing multiple arguments to api call

Tags: javascript, database, function, api, vue.js

I have a function called saveChanges that dispatches a call to an api that takes user input from a bunch of different input fields. Each field uses v-model with an object called editFormData. I then use each property in this object to pass as the arguments for the function that dispatches the api call. When I log out the params in the function that dispatches the api call, they all have the correct value that the user inputed. But if I log each argument in the api call where they're actually being used to send to the server, each argument is undefined. Am I passing the data over from the function to the api call wrong?

[image]

```
saveChanges(
      userId,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      title,
      company,
      profileEmail,
      bio,
      facebookLink,
      instagramLink,
      twitterLink,
      linkedinLink,
      youtubeLink,
      name,
      phone,
      address1,
      address2,
      city,
      state,
      zip,
    ) {
      const self = this;
      const loader = this.$loading.show();
      self.$store
        .dispatch(
          'updateUser',
          userId,
          firstName,
          lastName,
          title,
          company,
          profileEmail,
          bio,
          facebookLink,
          instagramLink,
          twitterLink,
          linkedinLink,
          youtubeLink,
          name,
          phone,
          address1,
          address2,
          city,
          state,
          zip,
        )
        .then(() => {
          this.reloadTable('');
          self.changeUserEditingStatus();
          loader.hide();
        })
        .catch(() => {
          // console.log(error);
          loader.hide();
        });
    },
```

Comment: Please include the full relevant source as text in code blocks rather than a screen shot.

Comment: I'll add the saveChanges function code. The api call is in the screenshot and I'm basically trying to get the arguments to not be undefined when they reach the api call

Comment: It's been added now

Comment: Thanks. The first thing I'd suggest is refactoring the list of values into a parameters object, otherwise hard to tell what is passed in what order. https://blog.novoda.com/refactoring-introduce-parameter-object/

Comment: I tried it but then I'm passing an object instead of just the values I want. But I see what you're saying, the way I'm writing it should still work though so still unsure why I'm seeing undefined when I log the values in the api call

Comment: The API service is submitting as an object anyway. It's too hard to troubleshoot with this many parameters, because order matters.

Comment: dispatch takes 2 arguments. pass an object instead of multiple args.

Comment: still getting returned all undefined

Comment: This seemed to work, passing the object as an argument and then instead of writing all of those params in the api call, I only require one which is payload(the object). Then I just write payload.firstName, payload.lastName, etc. It seems to be working